# Height not setting to the actual height of the div

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV that slides open to the height of the content, but for some reason on divs that have no content it's calculating the height wrong.

The 2nd blog entry down (Thoma) is a good example when expanded.

http://dririser.co.uk/index.php

The 'data-height' is 108px but it's setting the height of the DIV to 360px. The DIVs with content in work fine, it sets the correct height but seems to come to the wrong calculation on DIVs with no content in.

This is basically the jist of the code.

Set the hight as a value on the div.

```
$(".articleSlide").each(function () {
    var current = $(this);
    current.attr("data-height", current.height());
});
```

Set a variable then apply the height.

```
$(".showTeamList").toggle(function() {
    var open_height = $(".articleSlide").attr("data-height") + "px";
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({"height": open_height}, "slow" );
 }, function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({"height": "35"}, "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Stop writing tags in titles, please. You've done it on pretty much all of your 25 questions. :(

Comment: Stack Overflow has the tags feature to enable topics to be consistently displayed and indexed. Message-board style tags in titles is, thanks to this feature, obsolete... and redundant! They are thus discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that this line:

```
$(".articleSlide").attr("data-height")
```

Will only ever find the first element with class `.articleSlide` then use the `data-height` of that. You want it to find the `data-height` of the element that is specific for that button., just like you did with:

```
 $(this).parent().parent().animate({"height": open_height}, "slow" );
```

Try:

```
$(this).parents(".articleSlide").attr("data-height");
```

Answer (score -1):

height() "Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements."

it has the correct behavior because the computed height is none. you need to wrap the elements in an absolutely positioned container with overflow:hidden;height:0;